# Google currency converter api for large number of data

Tags: php

I am using google finance calculator to convert currency. I have to convert atleast = 2000 numbers to be converted at once. Below I have set only 10 numbers in the array. When I run this code, it is working fine but it is taking too much time. When I try with around 5000 numbers, it sometimes time out error. Can anybody help me how can I modify with my code for large number of datas. Thank you.  Below is code that I am currently using.

```
$amounts= array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100);
$from_Curr ='USD';
$to_Curr = 'THB';
$convertedCurrency = convertCurrency($amounts, $from_Curr, $to_Curr);
print_r($convertedCurrency);

function convertCurrency($amounts= array(), $from, $to){
    $convertedCurrency = array();
    foreach ($amounts as $amount) {
        $url  = "https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to";
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
        $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
        array_push($convertedCurrency, round($converted, 3));
    }
    return $convertedCurrency;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine a request gets anwered in 50ms, you can do the calculation yourself for 5000 requests...

Change the method of approaching the problem : exchange rates are linear, so you just need one answer, and you can do after the exchange calculation without the API. A multiplication operation is much faster than an API request. Ask the API for the counter value of 1 USD, and then multiply each USD amount by the obtained value :

```
$amounts = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100);

$from_Curr = 'USD';
$to_Curr = 'THB';

$convertedCurrency = convertCurrency($amounts, $from_Curr, $to_Curr);
print_r($amounts);
print_r($convertedCurrency);

function convertCurrency($amounts = array(), $from, $to) {
    $convertedCurrency = array();
    $amount = 1;

    $url = "https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*?)<\/span>/", $data, $converted);
    $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);

    foreach ($amounts as $amount) {
        $convertedCurrency[] = $amount * $converted;
    }

    return $convertedCurrency;
}
```

Sidenote: changed the regex to a non greedy match (.*?), in case spans are added lataer in the page.

Comment: although it is taking time there is no response time out this time. Thank you

Comment: @nas Glad it helped. You will still need the time to make one request to the API : usually answered in about 100-150ms. You cannot do much for this. After that, 5000 calculations will be done lightning fast. The time taken is spent in other operations like setting up your page and sending the data to the browser...

Answer (score 1):

You are using a free service right ? that's probably  why you are getting a timeout error.
there's a limit for requesting a response from the service which is why you get an error when that limit is reached. e.i how many requests over a specific  period of time

You either look for a paid service that can intake your requirements ( 5000 responses at once )

Or change your request to a lesser number of times ( lesser than 5000).

for the code itself , I know that foreach is considered slow, try another looping solution.

Comment: Yes I am using free one. i tried using while list, it has some improvement in processing but response time out is still there

Comment: it's hard to tell if the delay is from the response time or from the code. 
fyi you can try this free api and see if it makes a difference 
http://www.currencyconverterapi.com/pricing
maximum 100 request per hour.